# NodeJs project SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, import, export

I have a file in `./constant/assets` folder. when I am trying to run the program `node index.ts`
I get the following error;
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
this what I am trying to import

```
import {  USERNAME_SELECTOR, PASSWORD_SELECTOR, BUTTON_SELECTOR } from './constant/assets';
```

my assets file

```
export const  USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#UserName';
export const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#User_Password';
export const BUTTON_SELECTOR = '#LoginUserLoginButton';
```

I have been reading online, and people talk about using `<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>` but I dont think I am using that format. I have package.json

Comment: `node` does not support typescript.

Comment: @BertrandMarron  I am new to this, I have been reading manything online, so how do you import in node? isnt typescript for all the javascript codes?

Comment: Maybe start with https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/

Comment: @BertrandMarron Thank you :)

Comment: @BertrandMarron I just posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically for anyone out there looking for answer you need to do module export. you can export functions or variables

in the index page

```
const assets = require('./constant/assets');
```

the assets file

```
// a beginner film course
let film101 = {
    professor: 'Mr Caruthers',
    numberOfStudents: 20,
    level: 'easy'
}

// an expert film course
let film102 = {
    professor: 'Mrs Duguid',
    numberOfStudents: 8,
    level: 'challenging' 
}

// export the courses so other modules can use them
exports.film101 = film101;
exports.film102 = film102;
```